# Prerequisites for Using Composite Models in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, aggregation

Currently, my PowerBI report is getting its data from CSV files in Azure blob storage. Once all the data is extracted from the CSV files, I end up with about 9 million rows in my Sales fact table.

I have 10 fairly simple measures in my model (mostly sums and averages), with a Product dimension with a hierarchy that's 8 levels deep. (ProductKey, ProductName, Subcategory, Category...).  I have a matrix visual on my report canvas, with the Product hierarchy Rows and then the 10 measures on Values. Performance is brutal.

Can I fix this mess by "redirecting" the output of the PowerQuery that reads/parses the text files to write to a data warehouse in Azure, and then create aggregations for at least the simpler measures? (I read Phil Seamark's blog on Composite Models and Aggregations, and it looks like I could just use the fact table and aggregate on that, and then since a lot of the simpler measures would hit that, performance would improve.

Am I understanding this right? My data model is really simple:

DimProduct--SalesFact--DimStore
SalesFact--DimDate

Right now, I don't think there's any way to speed things up, because I don't think I can create an aggregation table without DirectQuery etc (backend in a database table).

if I'm missing something here, what is it?

That *should* fix my problem (I think), because for all but a few measures, I should be able to read from the aggregated fact table.

Thanks
Pieter

Comment: Keen to know if it is slow due to the amount of rows being pulled into your matrix. If you filtered on just one month, how does it perform? Or in a new page, just have card visuals for each measure (maybe one at a time), and how do those perform? The 8 levels deep of hierarchy, is this in your fact or dim table?

Comment: the 8 levels is in the dimension table. (Hopefully i'm not that dumb, but no telling these days). If I just do card visuals, they perform just fine, but that's because they're being calculated once, not once for every week in the date table.

Comment: How many weeks are you showing in the matrix? For example, if you were to filter on just one month (4-5 weeks), how does it perform? Could you share a snip of your matrix?

Comment: You can also explore creating your own aggregate table in PowerQuery. For example, add a custom column based on Year-WeekOfYear, then group on that with Product ID and Store ID. See how many rows that reduces to.

Comment: It's already summarized down to week of year. =)